# Compare data from same hour last week in ElastAlert

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elastalert

I'm trying to setup a alert in ElastAlert that will alert if the number of events on Monday 01:00 - 02:00 was 10% bigger or smaller than the same time period from Monday the week before.

Our data differs a lot from day to day, sunday compared to monday for example and also hour by hour.

Is there a way to use the spike type or any other filter to do this kinds of checks?

Comment: Hi where you about to get a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet I'm afraid. Please report back if you manage to find something

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of a problem. I ended up with the forking of elastAlert and adding new rule type.

Under the hood, it makes another ES call and compares the data. It is a little dirty and doesn't fit the original elastAlert architecture. But it does the thing.
It is a mix of 'spike' and 'metric_aggregation' rules.

https://github.com/spodgurskiy/elastalert

Here is the example of my rule configuration.

```
# Alert when there is a sudden spike comparing to the historical data
name: Spike detection

type: metric_history_aggregation
index: metrics-*

# Reference window diff in minutes
date_diff_ref: 10080

# Spike detection
threshold_total: 50
threshold_cur: 0
threshold_ref: 0

spike_height: 1.05
spike_type: both # <both/up/down>

# Aggregation
metric_agg_key: "<field_name>"
metric_agg_type: sum
max_threshold:

# Alert section
alert:
- "slack"
alert_display_timezone: US/Pacific
alert_text_type: exclude_fields
alert_subject: ""
slack_webhook_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/..."
```